# Установка глобальных переменных ларавель

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста как было бы правильно устанавливать глобальные переменные либо же переменные для главного шаблона. Т.е. я имею вот такое вот древо шаблонов
main.blade
index.blade (в котором наследую main.blade)
и т.д.
Как мне можно передать в шаблон main переменные с site-title и др. (конечно можно сделать костялми, но хотелось бы узнать как это делается правильно)

Answer (score 1):

Всё прекрасно описано в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).

- Используя фасады `View::share('key', 'value')`
- Используя хелпер `view()->share('key', 'value')`

Answer (score 0):

В main.blade в нужном месте вставьте

```
@yield('title')
```

В index.blade вставьте

```
@section('title', 'Page Title')
```

Документация: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#defining-a-layout